# Filter objects in range of value like id - Django

Tags: django, laravel

I want to filter objects which are in range of value in Django for example:

`array_id = [1,2,3,4]`

I want get objects which are in *[1,2,3,4]*

In Laravel I use this code :

```
$orders = Order::where('user_id',1)->get();
$array_id = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($order as $orders){
      $array_id[$i] = $order->id;
      $i++;
}
payments = Payment::whereIn('order_id',$array_id)->get();
```

I use `whereIn()` method in Laravel. How can I write this code in Django ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Seems like you accidentally added the django tag, which doesn't seem appropriate since it's Laravel Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `.filter(id__id=Array)`

Example: `MyObject.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3])` will get you all the objects whos id is 1, 2 or 3